# wp-signon error on password with special character

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem with wp_signon. When I try to use a password with the special character it says the wrong password even if it's not.

I'm using this code.

```
$info = array();
$info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
$info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
$info['remember'] = true;

$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );

if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
} else {
echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
}

die();
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Did you check it manually? . Below is working fine with @.

```
$info = array();
$info['user_login'] = 'admin';
$info['user_password'] = 'admin@123';
$info['remember'] = true;

$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );

if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
} else {
echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
}
```